# Are the Lido STF font installation instructions up-to-date?

Tags: fonts

The Czech TUG homepage has instructions and files to install the Lido STF fonts [here](http://www.cstug.cz/stormtype/slido-in-en.html). I don't know much about how fonts work in TeX, and the files have a modification date of 2001, so I'd like to ask:

1. Are these instructions up-to-date and correct? If not, please provide corrections.
2. Do I need to install the OFS package?  This is unclear for me from the instructions.
3. How do I invoke the font in my documents?

(I know I can just use XeTeX, but it's sometimes fun to do things like this. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.)

---

Here is a summary in case the link breaks.

1. Unpack the `.tgz` archive.
2. Insert the following line into `texmf/dvips/config/config.ps`:

   `p +slido.map`
3. Insert the following line into `texmf/pdftex/config/pdftex.cfg`:

   `map +slido.map`
4. In `texmf/web2c/mktex.cnf`, delete `fontmaps` from the line setting `MT-FEATURES`.
5. Run `texhash`.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @egreg MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: No don't change config.ps or pdftex.cfg. Maps are added via updmap/initexmf http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/advanced.html#psfonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Correct installation instructions for MiKTeX

1. Unpack the [`.tgz` archive](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/stormtype/slido.tgz) into your `texmf` tree.
2. In the command line run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`
3. A text file appears; enter `Map slido.map` (as the last line probably, the file was empty in my case, except a comment.) Save and close the file.
4. Run `texhash`.
5. Run `initexmf --mkmaps`.

(You may have to run all command line stuff as administrator, depending on whether you saved the files to a global texmf tree ("common root directory") or a local (user) one. All MiKTeX command line utils have the `--admin` option.)

In a LaTeX document you can now enable the font globally with

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{sld}
```

or locally with

```
\fontfamily{sld}\selectfont
```

The OFS package is not needed for basic usage of the font, but the homepage recommends installing it. It is needed if you want to `\usepackage{slido}` or `\input slido` because the provided `.sty` and `.tex` files use OFS macros.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{sld}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
éáűőúöüóí
\textbf{öüóőú \textit{éáűí}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my tree there is no `texmf` file, actually I dont have it at all. Is is possible tu use font Lido in pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @JanFilip texmf is not a directory name. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/