# XeTeX loads Lido STF incorrectly

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, fontspec

This is a followup to [Are the Lido STF font installation instructions up-to-date?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120172/are-the-lido-stf-font-installation-instructions-up-to-date). I have the Lido STF fonts installed as described there. I also have them installed in OpenType format in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. I'm using MiKTeX.

This code compiled with PDFLaTeX gives correct output, while compiling with XeLaTeX makes the first sentence bold italic and the second sentence regular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lido STF}
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{sld}
\fi

\begin{document}
{\itshape This is supposed to be italic.}
{\bfseries And this bold.}

\end{document}
```

Additionally Adobe Reader tells me that even when I use XeTeX, the Type1 fonts are used.

What is the problem and how do I fix it permanently?

Comment: If you have two version of a font (e.g. in your case a type1 and a opentype version) then it can happen that xetex gets confused and uses the wrong one or mixed them in the steps of the compilation. Use the filename in the `\setmainfont` to force xetex to use the open type version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a style file for loading the font (save as `lidostf.sty`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{lidostf}[2013/11/12]
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
    \RequirePackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[Extension=.otf,
                 BoldFont = *bold,
                 ItalicFont = *italic,
                 BoldItalicFont = *bolditalic,
                 Scale=0.93,
                 Ligatures=TeX]
                 {lidostf}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math} % or TeX Gyre Termes Math
\else
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{sld}
    \RequirePackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\fi
```

These issues are yet to be solved:

- How to choose between XITS Math and TeX Gyre Termes Math? [Functional difference between newtx, Times, Termes, STIX, XITS; text and math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141033/functional-difference-between-newtx-termes-math-and-xits)
- When using PDFTeX, how to scale the text font down or the math font up so that their height matches?